# ¿Cómo crear una aplicación de Windows Forms (c++) en Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms

Ya he trabajado con Windows forms en Visual Studio 2012, sin embargo por razones que no puedo explicar necesito usar VS2015 Community a partir de ahora y cada que intento crear una aplicación de WinForms me aparece este mensaje de error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo solucionar esto? Por que no he encontrado nada útil al respecto.

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser un defecto conocido y reportado aquí: [Start new Project - create form - get The data necessary to complete this operation not yet available](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1628507/start-new-project-create-form-get-the-data-necessary-to-complete-this-operation-not-yet-available). No parece que Microsoft lo haya resuelto todavía.

La única sugerencia que parece haber ayudado a algunos es de esperar un momento, cerrar `MyForm.h`, y volver a abrirlo a partir del "Solution Explorer" (no sé cómo se dice en español).

Answer (score 0):

Si es un problema que aun se mantiene en visual 2017, aunque en vs2017 se tiene que cerrar el proyector por completo y abrirlo desde la carpeta donde se localiza la solucion